# Photoshop paths to linear

Tags: photoshop, bezier, photoshop-script

I wonder if it's possible to loop over a Photoshop path and set all the points on it to be linear?

Unlike Illustrator, paths in Photoshop is not well documented and a bit cumbersome:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR // ERRORS ONLY DialogModes 2

//  create a document to work with
var docRef = app.documents.add(200, 200, 72, "untitled");

// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// create the array of PathPointInfo objects
var lineArray = new Array();
lineArray.push(new PathPointInfo());
lineArray[0].kind = PointKind.SMOOTHPOINT;
lineArray[0].anchor = new Array(50, 100); // A
lineArray[0].leftDirection =  [0, 0];
lineArray[0].rightDirection = lineArray[0].anchor;

lineArray.push(new PathPointInfo());
lineArray[1].kind = PointKind.SMOOTHPOINT;
lineArray[1].anchor = new Array(150, 150); // B
lineArray[1].leftDirection = [0, 0];
lineArray[1].rightDirection =  [0, 0];


// create a SubPathInfo object, which holds the line array in its entireSubPath property.
var lineSubPathArray = new Array();
lineSubPathArray.push(new SubPathInfo());
lineSubPathArray[0].operation = ShapeOperation.SHAPEXOR;
lineSubPathArray[0].closed = false;
lineSubPathArray[0].entireSubPath = lineArray;

pathName = "my path";

//create the path item, passing subpath to add method
var myPathItem = docRef.pathItems.add(pathName, lineSubPathArray);

// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL


myPath = srcDoc.pathItems.getByName(pathName);
var subPathCount = myPath.subPathItems.length; // Count of subpaths

var msg = "";

msg += subPathCount + " path(s)\n";


for (var i = 0; i < myPath.subPathItems.length; i++)
{
  msg += myPath.subPathItems[i] + "\n";
}

alert(msg);
```

Firstly, I'm having difficulty access the subPathItems items after I created the path.
Secondly, I don't know what the settings for the tangents (.leftDirection, .rightDirection) are for a linear path.

Apart from that it's peachy ;)

Comment: Not sure, but I do remember writing some fairly straight forward path operating code a few years ago, and PS's actionscript sure as heck hasn't modernized since, so... maybe https://github.com/Pomax/photoshop-paths-to-SVG/blob/master/pathtosvg.jsx is useful to you as "oh so that's how you X" resource

Comment: I've tried to log manual process of convert bezier path using scriptlistener plugin, I've found that everytime you manually does that, Action script runs 2 commands, one is enter and exit. so basically as far as I'm concerned action script nor photoshop DOM have direct capabilities of doing that so I think it would be nearly impossible to perform this action, You may still get succeed on getting path points but I think DOM won't allow modifying it.